Roblox Studio: Holding down LeftControl as an in-game keybind activates Roblox Studio Shortcuts
I've been making a small experience within Roblox Studio recently and wanted to add crouching into the game. I used my (already functioning) code for sprinting and modified it to make a crouch button that only makes you crouch while the button is held.
When I tested this out for the first time, I tried pressing A to move left while crouching. Instead, this activated the shortcut for selecting all children within the Workspace, Ctrl+A. The same situation occurred when moving right with D; it instead thought I was trying to duplicate instances with Ctrl+D.
I have no idea why it does this or how I could fix it, how could I solve this problem? (Other than just... rebinding crouch to a different button. I know I can do that, but I still want to know why this even happens.)
I'll provide the code if requested, but since it works just fine on any key other than left Ctrl. I don't think it's a problem.

One way people get around this issue is just by making it a toggle rather than something you need to hold. This comes with multiple benefits though for example, some keyboard have ctrl in a spot that can be difficult to hold. Also it prevents other keybinds from being pressed during gameplay.
This happens though because ctrl is normally meant for keybinds, rather than a key itself. I would also suggest using a key like C because generally this is a much easier key to reach and shouldn't activate keybinds regardless of the situation.
